# Calculate average of a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I have the below table..the percent column is of type nvarchar

```
Data  Percent1 Percent2 Percent3
1     3%        4%        6%
2     6%        8%        7%
3     8%        6%        8%
```

I have to calculate the Avg per line so I get results like
Data Avg

```
1    4.33%
```

I was trying to convert the %column into decimal so I can apply the average function

```
select
Case WHEN Isnumeric([Percent1]) = 1
THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),Replace([Percent1],'%',''))
ELSE 0 END AS Percent1
from DashboardData
```

but I am just getting 0 values..I am guessing the outer function is running before the inner for some reason. Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this.

I know the IsNumeric function will make it 0 but I tried it before that and I was getting an exception that type is not a number.

Thanks

Comment: Fix your schema and store the numbers using a numeric type. The name of the column should make it clear that these are percents. If you really do need to indicate a unit of some sort with a string, as the number can be something other than percents, then make an extra column for it an store the unit there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but that column data just comes from an Excel bulk import which I don't have much control over.

Comment: Give the Excel guys a hint, that they can format cells if they want to display a unit after or before a number.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select dd.*, s.average      
from dashboarddata dd cross apply
     (select avg(try_convert(numeric(10, 2), replace(pc, '%', ''))) as average
      from values (percent1), (percent2), (percent3)) as v(pc)
     ) s;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon..tried that but getting an error 'numeric' is not a recognized built-in function name...using Sql Server 2014

Comment: @user1221989 . . . `numeric` is a data type.  You can use `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT ISNUMERIC('3%')` will return 0, as will all the rest of your values, so your else condition will always be the result.

Just drop the `%`

```
select
   data, 
   (replace(Percent1,'%','') + replace(Percent2,'%','') + replace(Percent3,'%','')) * 1.0 / 3
```

Note, if any of these values are `NULL` you need to account for that because `NULL` + anything `IS NULL`.

Also, you don't want to lean on `ISNUMERIC` too heavy... it can produce some results you probably aren't expecting

```
select 
    ISNUMERIC('$')      --money which is a numeric value
    ,ISNUMERIC('1e4')   --scientific notation
    ,ISNUMERIC('45D-1') --old scientific notation
    ,ISNUMERIC('.')     --just the decimal portion of a float / decimal
```

Comment: most forget about the old scientific notation